# with if/else column value, select different table and column

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, postgresql-9.3

objective
I have table like below, 
I want to select `comment` tbl,
but only return `comment` rows check related table `status` column all equal input param.

problem
In query 1, comment out I highlight, and it works otherwise return zero row. 
or 
query 2  get error syntax

How to solve this?

table

```
comment
id | endpoint_code | endpoint_id | status | create_by_user_id
1  | 1             | 56          | 0      | 1
2  | 0             | 27          | 0      | 1

description:   
endpoint_code  0:gallery tbl 1:media tbl  
use `endpoint_code` value if `0` means `endpoint_id` is point to `gallery` tbl,  
if `1` means point to `media` tbl.


user
id | status 
1  | 0 

gallery
id | status | ...
56 | 0

media
id | status | ...
27 | 0

category_gallery
id | category_id | gallery_id | ...
...

gallery_media
id | gallery_id | media_id | ...
...
```

query 1

```
SELECT c.* ,
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery,
  row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  FROM comment c
    LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id

    LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN "user" mcbu ON mcbu.id = m.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.media_id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN gallery mg ON mg.id = gm.gallery_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1

    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN "user" gcbu ON gcbu.id = g.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category_gallery cg ON cg.gallery_id = g.id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category ca ON ca.id = cg.category_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0 

    WHERE c.status = $1 
      AND u.status = $1 

      // comment out these for c.endpoint_code 0 (gallery)
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
        THEN 
          m.status = $1
        END
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
        THEN 
          mcbu.status = $1
        END
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
        THEN 
          mg.status = $1
        END
      //


      // or comment out these for c.endpoint_code 1 (media)
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0
        THEN 
          g.status = $1
        END
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0
        THEN 
          gcbu.status = $1
        END
      AND 
        CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0
        THEN 
          ca.status = $1
        END
      //

    AND c.id = $2
```

query 2
error

```
SELECT c.* ,
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery,
  row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  FROM comment c
    LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id

    LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN "user" mcbu ON mcbu.id = m.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.media_id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN gallery mg ON mg.id = gm.gallery_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1

    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN "user" gcbu ON gcbu.id = g.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category_gallery cg ON cg.gallery_id = g.id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category ca ON ca.id = cg.category_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0 

    WHERE c.status = $1 
      AND u.status = $1 

      CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
      THEN 
        AND 
          m.status = $1
        AND 
          mcbu.status = $1
        AND 
          mg.status = $1
      END


      CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0
      THEN 
        AND 
          g.status = $1
        AND 
          gcbu.status = $1
        AND 
          ca.status = $1
      END

    AND c.id = $2
```

I doing this in javascript generate query string from a function
input `status` params is option like below, I hope to find a way solve above problem, 
prefer not restruct the code too much will be best

query 2 for example

```
var query = `

SELECT c.* ,
  row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery,
  row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  FROM comment c
    LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id


    LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
`;

if (inputOption.status != 'undefined') {
query += `
    LEFT JOIN "user" mcbu ON mcbu.id = m.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
    LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.media_id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
`;
}
query += `
    LEFT JOIN gallery mg ON mg.id = gm.gallery_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 1
`;

query += `
    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.id = c.endpoint_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
`;
if (inputOption.status != 'undefined') {
query += `
    LEFT JOIN "user" gcbu ON gcbu.id = g.create_by_user_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category_gallery cg ON cg.gallery_id = g.id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0
    LEFT JOIN category ca ON ca.id = cg.category_id
      AND c.endpoint_code = 0 
`;
}

if (inputOption.status != 'undefined') {
query += `
    WHERE c.status = $1 
      AND u.status = $1 

      CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
      THEN 
        AND 
          m.status = $1
        AND 
          mcbu.status = $1
        AND 
          mg.status = $1
      END


      CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0
      THEN 
        AND 
          g.status = $1
        AND 
          gcbu.status = $1
        AND 
          ca.status = $1
      END
`;
}
query += `
    AND c.id = $2
`;
```

#### Edit: further questions

after I do select

```
SELECT c.* ,
    row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, 
    row_to_json(m.*) as media,
    row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  FROM comment c

  LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id

.... other query
  query += `
WHERE c.status = $1 
  AND u.status = $1 
  AND
  (
    (c.endpoint_code = 1
     AND m.status = $1
     AND mcbu.status = $1
     AND mg.status = $1
    )
    OR
....
```

the json result because `endpoint_code = 0` so in json key `media_gallery` and `media` ( from above query part `row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, ...`) value will be null.
or `endpoint_code = 1` key `gallery` value is null.

How to filter/remove if `endpoint_code = 0` then don't output `media_gallery` `media`, means don't do `row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, ...` in query? or other way ?

```
rows: 
[ { id: 7,
  endpoint_code: 0,
  endpoint_id: 27,
  status: 0,

  media_gallery: null,
  media: null,
  gallery: 
   { id: 27,
     status: 0,
     create_date: 
   ...
```

try to get result like

```
rows: 
[ { id: 7,
  endpoint_code: 0,
  endpoint_id: 27,
  status: 0,

  gallery: 
   { id: 27,
     status: 0,
     create_date: 
   ...
```

or

```
rows: 
[ { id: 7,
  endpoint_code: 1,
  endpoint_id: 27,
  status: 0,

  media_gallery: {
    id: ....
  },
  media: 
   { id: 27,
     status: 0,
     create_date: 
   ...
```

Comment: Too much code for me to read, but the general tip is to use AND/OR instead of CASE expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If you're filtering by user (`WHERE ... AND u.status = $1`) then it's pointless to LEFT JOIN "user", use JOIN instead.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister thanks for point it, does the join is faster than left join, right?

Comment: @jarlh thanks for reply, sorry for so much code, I cut them less I can.. thanks for the tip I'll try use and/or instead of case now

Comment: @user1575921 join may be faster than left join, but not necessarily. It's good practice to use only left join when you mean it though

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE doesn't work as a template, but rather as a function. Update your javascript as follows:

```
if (inputOption.status != 'undefined') {
query += `
    WHERE c.status = $1 
      AND u.status = $1 

      AND CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1 -- this will return a boolean
      THEN m.status = $1
       AND mcbu.status = $1
       AND mg.status = $1
      END   

      AND CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0 -- this too
      THEN g.status = $1
       AND gcbu.status = $1
       AND ca.status = $1
      END
`;
```

The above works, but it doesn't allow PostgreSQL to optimise the query. It is much better if you use AND and OR, as @jarlh states in the comments:

```
if (inputOption.status != 'undefined') {
query += `
    WHERE c.status = $1 
      AND u.status = $1 
      AND
      (
        (c.endpoint_code = 1
         AND m.status = $1
         AND mcbu.status = $1
         AND mg.status = $1
        )
        OR
        (c.endpoint_code = 0
         AND g.status = $1
         AND gcbu.status = $1
         AND ca.status = $1)
      )
`;
```

Comment: thanks for show me the example, its work!! I have a further question, the query  `SELECT  c.* row, row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, ... ` is it possible use case when or other way to only select base on `endpoint.code` value select specific table, like  if `endpoint.code = 0` remove line `row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, row_to_json(m.*) as media,`

Comment: @user1575921 A table must always return the same columns, and maintain consistency of datatypes across rows. If you can maintain the same row structure, then you can, e.g.: `CASE WHEN endpoint.code = 0 THEN row_to_json(g.*) ELSE row_to_json(m.*) END as gallery_or_media`

Comment: those tables doesn't have same columns, does that means I can't remove them if  output to json attribute value is null?  I tried `COALESCE` or `json_strip_nulls ` but I'm not sure doing correctly..

Comment: @user1575921 If by "those tables" you refer to the tables whose rows that you convert to a single JSON value each, whatever is in a JSON value is irrelevant (whether a single value, an array, an object with 1 element or an object with a million elements), a JSON value is always just a JSON value.

Comment: @ Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister So the answer is no right? I can't do it in  query, stop output null value from `row_to_json` . If so I will loop the output result, remove those json attribute outside the database with other language

Comment: @user1575921 I don't understand your question. How about you update your questions (add an "###Edit: further questions" line at the end followed by whatever you're asking, with whatever examples and desired output) and let me know, and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the second part of your question, you seem to be retrieving the results of your query as a single JSON document, with a `rows` object that is an array of the actual rows returned by your query. If this is what you want, then you could select use the `jsonb_strip_nulls()` function on the whole row returned:

```
SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY(
  SELECT json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(r.*)) AS comment
  FROM (
    SELECT c.* ,
      row_to_json(m.*) as media,
      row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery,
      row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
    ...
    ) r
  )) AS rows
```

Comment: thanks so much the example code,  I think I get it, I will try this in my code

Comment: do you suggest I doing query like this (  consider performance, retrieve json data like this is it too complicate in sql ? ), or should I just loop the rows remove attribute after, in javascript or other language I use at server side

Comment: @user1575921 it is not what PostgreSQL was originally designed for, but increasing use and reliance on JSON and XML is changing that, and it currently performs very well for this kind of results (especially with JSONB).

Comment: I'll give it a try with my project production version